# flex positioning. How to position one child of a flex-container differently

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox

I have the following situation. A flex container has children displayed as in:

```
  [                     [div1] [div2] [div3] [div4]]
```

The container's relevant CSS is set to:

```
  display:flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
```

The inner child divs are set with display: inline-flex. After this CSS is set, over which I have no control initially, I want to position only the first div, div1 to start at the beginning as shown below:

```
  [[div1]                       [div2] [div3] [div4]]
```

What is the CSS to be applied in JQuery to div1 to do so. I could take div1 and group the other divs into one element by putting a wrapper around them but that breaks other CSS pre-applied to the grouped-divs over which I have no control. Therefore, I am seeking an alternate solution without introducing any wrappers.

EDIT: I think that I am looking for the equivalent of *align-self* for *align-content* or *justify-content*. align-self only works for align-items to target a specific element.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  
}
li:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
  <li>Div1</li>
  <li>Div2</li>
  <li>Div3</li>
  <li>Div4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: I cannot use wrappers.  ul is, in effect, a wrapper. Also, you are changing the basic structure. I have no control over it and inserting a wrapper, breaks other CSS, elsewhere which refers to immediate parent. I do not want to change that and in fact have no control over it.

Comment: you don't need container wrapper but you need the ul wrapper to flex to work properly